# Wordpress and PHP Version Upgrade issue

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu-14.04, php5

I am running PHP Version 5.6 on my Ubuntu 14.04 Server.

```
/home/ubuntu# php -v
PHP 5.6.36-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

But when I am activating a theme I am getting below error

> Your server's PHP version (5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24) is not supported.
>
> This version is old, insecure and slow. Please update it as soon as
>   possible.

Any insights why this is happening?

Comment: WordPress itself works with PHP 5.2+, but that doesn't mean themes/plugins have to do so. Chances are the particular theme you're using wants to use certain PHP features only available in 5.6 or 7.x. Your PHP CLI version may not be the same one on the webserver. Check the output of `phpinfo()` on a `.php` file in the browser.

Comment: Yes but my server has version 5.6 still I am getting the error message

Comment: Sorry, I submitted the comment too fast. See my edit.

Comment: Yes the PHP.ini file that loaded has version PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24 how do I change this so that correct php.ini file will load for version 5.6

Comment: Well, it's not so much the `php.ini` as your webserver setup. If you're using Apache, you probably need to update your `libapache2-mod-php5` package.